# How to improve a GIF displaying program in WinApi

Tags: c++, winapi, gif

I'm working on a GIF program. Basically I've everything i need and the program is working, but the problem is that the frames displaying is a little bit slower than it should be (compared to GIF animations in the browsers for example, although I set the timer to the proper time). Important excerpts from my program:

```
// converting the frames to DDBs to perform the fastest BitBlt
for(int i=0;i<gifImage->getFramesQuantity();i++)
{
    frames_bitmaps[i]=(HBITMAP)CreateDIBitmap(GetDC(hwnd),
                      &(gifImage->getFrame(i)->bmpInfoHeader),
                      CBM_INIT,gifImage->getFrame(i)->bmpImgData,
                      gifImage->getFrame(i)->bmpInfo2,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
}

// setting timeBeginPeriod to ensure receiving WM_TIMER in the exact time
timeBeginPeriod(1)

void GIFWindow::onDCChange()
{
    ReleaseDC(hwnd,hdc);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);

    hdc=GetDC(hwnd);
    hdcMem=CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); 
}

// frame drawing function
void GIFWindow::drawFrame()
{
    SelectObject(hdcMem,frames_bitmaps[current_bitmap]);
    BitBlt(hdc,image_x,image_y,gifImage->getWidth(),gifImage->getHeight(),hdcMem,0,0,SRCCOPY);
}

void GIFWindow::startAnimation()
{ 
    drawFrame();
                                                                 // returns the delay in ms
    SetTimer( hwnd, TIMER_ID, gifImage->getFrame(current_bitmap)->getDelay(), NULL );
}

void GIFWindow::onTimer(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    KillTimer( hwnd, TIMER_ID);

    if(current_bitmap==gifImage->getFramesQuantity()-1)
        current_bitmap=0;
    else
        current_bitmap++;

    drawFrame();

    SetTimer( hwnd, TIMER_ID, gifImage->getFrame(current_bitmap)->getDelay(), NULL );
}
```

I would appreciate any comments about my code and ideas how can I improve the performance

Comment: Any reason you are creating a compatible DC *every* frame?

Comment: Also I believe that GIF Frame delay is in 100th of a second, whilst the `SetTimer` method is in 1000ths (milliseconds).

Comment: @Moo-Juice Hmm should I track then when the dc changes (ex. on WM_SIZE etc) and only in this case create new hdcMem? I've never seen any example of a program that doesn't do it like mine that's why I didn't know it can be different.

Comment: @Moo-Juice Yes, but the function returns the time in milliseconds not 1/100th of a second. I'll edit my post to make it clear

Comment: Yes, typically when I have done blitting, I will have a memory DC recreated/created on WM_SIZE.  It's a good place to do it as when your window is first created, it gets a WM_SIZE message then too!

Comment: @Moo-Juice Updated, thank you! Still didn't do the job though.. What if I have written the drawing for example using the OpenGL library? Any chances that it could help?

Comment: `SetTimer()` is not that accurate and not really good enough for animation playback. You may want to look at e.g. [CreateWaitableTimer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682492(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Jonathan Potter Thank you very much, yes this was the problem. Just wanted to post the solution and found out your answer! I changed the SetTimer() function to the CreateTimerQueueTimer() func and it works perfectly. Thanks again!